# Untar is confused about file existence

Tags: r, tar

When I call the R function `untar("myfile.tar.gz", files = vector_of_file_names)` the inner files get extracted perfectly fine, but the following output appears on the console for all of them:

```
/bin/tar: folder/subfolder/somefile.R: Not found in archive
```

Again, the files *do* get extracted just fine, I can inspect them, the operation is a success. So why is `untar()` complaining? I cannot even suppress these messages with `suppressWarnings()` or `supressMessages()`, I guess because they are produced by a `system()` call inside `untar()`.

Any insight as to why this could be happening or what to investigate next would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** The `vector_of_file_names` includes complete file paths, e.g. `folder/subfolder/somefile.R` and not just `somefile.R`.

Comment: You need to provide names of folders and subfolders with slashes in the `vector_of_file_names`, like if a folder name is algo and sub items in it are abc.txt and def.txt then your command should be `untar('myfile.tar', files=c('algo/abc.txt', 'algo/def.txt'))`, with only file names it doesn't work, the reason I am little surprised that it should not have extracted those files.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! This part does not surprise me, because my vector of filenames _does_ include complete paths, so they get extracted ok. I should have made it clear in the question, going to do that now.

Comment: Thanks, now this is strange, not sure completely there what is happening